# Передача переменных из JS в HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom, namespace, variable

Нужно сделать так, чтобы в HTML коде (в тексте самой страницы) появлялись определенные значения переменных, которые рассчитываются в .js файле , сейчас я делаю это так:

```
let variable = 123;
document.getElementById('variable').innerHTML = variable;

<p>Текст в HTML: <span id = variable></span></p>
```

Но мне кажется это каким то костылем, так как при большом количестве переменных код в js выглядит очень громоздко, к тому же значение id должно быть уникальным, таким образом я не могу использовать одну и ту же переменную больше 1 раза

Подскажите решение

Comment: Это не костыль...так тоже делают. Но обычно информацию держат в атрибутах `data-[название]`

Answer (score 1):

Весь вопрос в том, откуда именно берутся переменные и где именно в HTML они должны выводиться. Если переменные можно упаковать в массив, то вывести все значения можно, например, в цикле, динамически создавая span'ы и заполняя их значениями:

```js
const vars = [123, 456, 789, 101112, 131415, 161718];

const p = document.getElementById('from-js');

for(let i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  p.appendChild(span).textContent = vars[i];
}
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<p id="from-js"></p>
```